# Adding rules to validate() with grouping

Tags: jquery, validation

The form is at:
http://fuzzysiberians.com/app4.cfm?a=1

I am using:

```
$('#sec_ssn3').rules("add", {
    groups: {
        ssn:"sec_ssn1 sec_ssn2 sec_ssn3"
    }, 
    required:true,
    number: true,
    messages: {
        required: " <span style='color:red;'>Please enter co-applicant's social security number</span>"
    }
});
```

If the co-applicant checkbox is checked, I ask for co-applicants social security number. The grouping somewhat works but how do i get rid of the repeat error messages? The last one doesn't even go away once a number is entered. The ssn for primary applicant works great. 
On the main validate() function, I added:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "ssn1" || element.attr("name") == "ssn2" || element.attr("name") == "ssn3" )
        error.insertAfter("#ssn3");
    else if (element.attr("name") == "sec_ssn1" || element.attr("name") == "sec_ssn2" || element.attr("name") == "sec_ssn3" )
        error.insertAfter("#sec_ssn3");
    else 
        error.insertAfter(element); 
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't like that.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) there might be a better way to set up your rules.

Example from above link:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     contact: {
       required: true,
       email: {
         depends: function(element) {
           return $("#contactform_email:checked")
         }
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Using the "depends" option you can set up validation on the element based on the coApp checkbox  being checked. Try moving all the rules to the .validate() and adding

`depends: function(element){ return $("#coApp").is(":checked"); }`

for all the co-applicant validation.

Give that a shot and let me know.

Don't forget to revalidate/parse server side as well!